# How to send client details to server from javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am writing a vue.js application and as per the requirement, I have to collect the browser details, os details, client ip address and a few other details and attach this to every HTTP request.

I have collected all those details and now in the interceptor function. Now my question is how to send this to server? Is there any specific header only for this purpose ? It will be very helpful if someone can help me to suggest the best practice in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: The client IP is already an intrinsic part of any HTTP request, and info like the OS and browser details are part of the standard User-Agent header. You shouldn’t really need to do anything here.

Comment: Opinionated best practice would be to not collect this info, privacy is a real concern nowadays and it will redflag your site to anyone using privacy extensions... https://pixelprivacy.com/resources/browser-fingerprinting/ There are less intrusive ways to track users

Comment: @kkarakk so how will you implement any kind of bot mitigation? No-one is saying this information will be saved and utilised for anything else than tracking the usage

Comment: @mplungjan if users don't want you tracking their usage are you giving them an opt-out? if not, then it is problematic and fuels usage of privacy extensions and vpns(which means you will present incorrect data as usage statistics or even drive away privacy minded users like me)...

Comment: @kkarakk So be it. We also block TOR access because 99% of the access was from bots. We need to know the size of the audience to size the backend appropriately

Comment: @mplungjan that's your prerogative, usage of anonymization services is only going to increase as we're seeing increasing linkage of web usage tracking to real world negative consequences(like china's social points system for eg)